# Can an HTTP error other than 404 be used for custom landing pages?

Tags: http, joomla, iis-7

Context: II7 on Windows7. Joomla! 1.5

At present I have the incoming traffic entire an URL like http://mywebsite/mylandingpage and I have Joomla! redirect to a custom 404 page for each string after the /.

Could I do the same with 403? If I have, for example, a /anotherlandingpage as a subdirectory without view-contents privileges, a 403 will fire. Is it possible to hook into that?

I've tried but at the moment, IIS7 seems to be catching it before Joomla! loads.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a Web.Config page in your root directory, and use that to tell IIS where to redirect to when an error happens.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx is the documentation, which includes an example of redirecting a 500 error.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors defaultRedirect="GenericError.htm"
                  mode="RemoteOnly">
      <error statusCode="500"
             redirect="InternalError.htm"/>
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

As @mikel suggests you can use web.config. But if you are going to use that, you might as well use URLRewrite. With that you can write custom rules to tell IIS to redirect specific URLs to different target pages. It is what is used for pretty url's in many cms's.

With URL rewrite you can redirect

`http://www.somedomain.com/123/whatever_the_title?andparameter=2`

to

`http://www.somedomain.com/index.html?page=123&andparameter=2`

More information on URLRewrite can be found at http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite and if you Google for URLRewrite you will get plenty of links with examples of how to write URLRewrite rules.

BTW URLRewrite is a standard IIS extension (at least with IIS7), but you(your ISP) may need(s) to enable it for the site(s).